# Link with hover overlay is opened on first click on mobile device

Tags: css, css-transitions

I have a div that displays another content on hover using css transitions.

There is one text element `<h3>Another Text</h3>` that overlays link `<a href="mailto:x@x.x">email adress</a>`. On desktop browser it's working correctly - I can click the link after hover is activated. On phone device where hover is replaced by clicking on the element, there's a problem - If I activate the hover by clicking on "Another Text" it opens the link right away.

My question is if there is any way how to restrict link opening on first click.
Ideal scenario on phone device is:

1. user clicks on "Another text"
2. hover is activated, link is displayedbut not fired
3. user click link and link is fired

Here is the code: https://jsfiddle.net/9bc0bcja/2/

Comment: Yes, this is expected behaviour and you need to design your pages for the mobile in a different way.

Comment: You are looking for :focus

Answer (score 0):

I've partially solved it using javscript:

```
$(".team-social")
.bind("transitionend webkitTransitionEnd oTransitionEnd MSTransitionEnd",
 function(e){
    if($(this).hasClass("pointerA")){
     if(is_touch_device()){
        $(this).removeClass( "pointerA" );
     }
    }
    else{
     $(this).addClass( "pointerA" );
    }
 });
$('.team-social a').click(function() { 
if(is_touch_device()){
  $(this).parent().removeClass("pointerA");
}
});
```

It activates pointer-events after transition finishes, so it is not fired right away when I click overlay on phone device.

https://jsfiddle.net/9bc0bcja/4/

- added javascript + jquery link
- added class `.pointerA`
- added `pointer-events:none;` to class `.team-social`

Answer (score 0):

[Try this Fiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/6djqL9rw/18/)

I simplified your code, keeping only the necessary elements.

This script only operates if you're using a mobile device, which is what you should want for performance reasons.

This code watches the hover event rather than transitionEnd, that way the function trigger timing is not dependent on the length of the transition.

```
if (is_touch_device()) {
    var $wrap = $(".wrap"),
        $pw = $wrap.find(".pointer-watch"),
        $tc = $pw.find(".transition-container");

    $pw.addClass("pointerN");
    $('.wrap').hover(function wrapHovered() {
        if ($pw.hasClass("pointerN")){
            setTimeout(function enablePE() {
                $pw.removeClass("pointerN");
            }, 0);
        }
        else if (!$wrap.is(":hover")) {
            $pw.addClass("pointerN");
        }
   });
}
```